# Android manifest merge. Skipped build type manifests

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

I use Android studio & gradle v2.2.3 and have tried to merge manifests from `src/main` folder and `src/androidTest` or `src/debug` folders.

This is manifest from **main** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample"
>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.Application"
    >
    <activity android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.ui.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and from **androidTest** or **debug** folder (no matter where it is located):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.Application"
    >

    <activity
        android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.ui.TestActivity"/>
</application>
```

The problem is that manifest from **debug** or **androidTest** folder is completely ignored. But i try to declare `TestActivity` only in the test manifest. Result manifest after merge is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<application
    android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample.ui.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also any mention about missed manifest doesn't present in `manifest-merger-debug-report`. There are only **main** and libraries manifests.

also `android` part of app `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    testBuildType "debug"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.beloo.chipslayoutmanager.sample"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

As you see i've tried to mention explicitly `testBuildType "debug"` here, that haven't help.

and project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

project.ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 25
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Maybe you will be able to see my mistake, because i can't.